# Is $m$ a projective $A$-module?

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, projective-module

> $A$ is a Noetherian local ring and $m$ be its maximal ideal. Then is $m$ a projective $A$-module?

I got this problem while solving another problem. Can anyone please help me to figure it out?

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the ring. For instance, if $R=\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ is the localization of $\mathbb{Z}$ at the prime ideal $p$, then the maximal ideal is principal, so isomorphic as a module to the ring itself, hence projective.

In case the ring is $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$, the maximal ideal is not projective.

---

*Added from comment.*

If your aim is to discuss $\def\Tor{\operatorname{Tor}}\Tor^A_1(A/m,M)$, then projectivity of $m$ is not involved. Given any $A$-module $M$, from the exact sequence
$$
0\to m\to A\to A/m\to0
$$
we get the following final fragment of the long exact sequence obtained by applying $-\otimes_AM$:
$$
\Tor^A_1(A,M)\to\Tor^A_1(A/m)\to m\otimes_AM\to A\otimes_AM\to
A/m\otimes_AM\to0
$$
Since $A$ is projective (hence flat), $\Tor^A_1(A,M)=0$, so we can state that

> $\Tor^A_1(A/m,M)=0$ if and only if $m\otimes_AM\to A\otimes_AM$ is injective.

Projectivity of the maximal ideal $m$ is not involved here and neither is the fact that $A$ is a local ring. This holds for *any* ring and *any* (right) ideal $m$ of $A$.

Of course, if you know from other results that $m\otimes_AM\to A\otimes_AM$ is injective in your specific case, then you have as a consequence that $\Tor^A_1(A/m,M)=0$.

Comment: The original question I am solving asks to show if $M$ is a finitely generated $A-$ module and if the mapping from $m\otimes M$ to $A\otimes M$ is injective then $Tor_1^A(M,A/m)=0$. I found an answer which states that $0\rightarrow m \rightarrow A \rightarrow A/m \rightarrow 0$ is exact and hence $0\rightarrow m\otimes M \rightarrow A\otimes M \rightarrow (A/m)\otimes M \rightarrow 0$ is exact and hence the result. My problem is, to say it, we have to have that $m$ is projective. Isn't it?

Comment: @EpsilonDelta I added some details to my answer (even if it isn't linked to the question).

Comment: But in order to define $Tor_1^A(A/m,M)$ we should have a projective resolution of $A/m$. What is the projective resolution you consider here?

Comment: @EpsilonDelta It's completely immaterial what projective resolution you consider: Tor is independent of it.

Comment: Ok as I learned the definition of Tor involves a projective resolution. What definition do you use for Tor?

Comment: @EpsilonDelta The standard one. You just need to know that any module has a projective resolution (which is true).

Comment: Can you please mention the standard definition? I just want to know whether I have learned a wrong definition.

Comment: @EpsilonDelta Sorry, no. The facts I mentioned can be found in every book about homological algebra. Please ask a new question if you have doubts, but first check about the long exact sequence of derived functors.

Comment: @EpsilonDelta, he is not using $0\to m\to A\to A/m\to 0$ as a projective resolution of $A/m$ to compute $Tor(A/m,-)$, and he can' t since $m$ is in general not projective. He is talking about the long exact sequence for $Tor(-,M)$ with respect to its first argument corresponding to that short exact sequence.

Comment: I know. I just asked the standard definition of Tor. egreg says it does not involve projective resolution and I have learned that it invovels. So I am confused and that's why I asked the correct definition.

Comment: And I don't understand how can one get that long exact sequence from that short exact one.

Comment: @EpsilonDelta Please, reread my text: I said that ***projectivity of $$*** is not involved, not that projective modules aren't involved. The long exact sequence is a very standard fact about Tor. Check your textbook. Also the fact that Tor is independent of the projective resolution used for computing it is very basic.

Answer (score 4):

Over a local commutative ring, projective modules coincide with  free modules, so the question is whether $\mathfrak m$ is free.
If it is free it must be of rank one, because two elements of $a,b\in A$ are necessarily $A$-linearly dependent: $a\cdot b-b\cdot a=0$  (duh!)
Freeness of dimension one means that for some $m\in \mathfrak m$ the $A$-linear map $A\to \mathfrak m:a\mapsto am$ is bijective. Hence we get:

**Theorem:**
The maximal ideal  of a commutative local ring is projective iff it can be generated by an element which is not a zero-divisor .

**Important  example:**
If $(A,\mathfrak m)$ is a noetherian local **domain**, then  $\mathfrak m$ is projective iff $A$ is a *discrete valuation ring*.